# Can I use some body html in wordpress avada theme?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

Can I use some body html in wordpress avada theme In several columns with cod block?

Is this right?
Speed not come down?

See the image below:
[image]

Comment: what do you mean body html? Like <body>SOME OTHER CODE</body>?

Comment: @klo Yes, Inside the body in different sections.

Comment: Well, you cant put body tag inside body (and any theme will provide body tag by default). If you want to load another page inside existing page use iframe.

Comment: – klo Thank you for help :) @klo